# How to run multiple map-reduce jobs in parallel

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I have ***four*** different map-reduce jobs operating on the same data set. I have a Hadoop cluster for storage and processing of the data. The question is , how can i run the four jobs in parallel without running them sequentially from a Linux shell ? I have read about workflow-management systems like `Apache Oozie`. In this situation, whether i need to use oozie or is there any other easy way ? Any help would be appreciated . Thanks !

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988809/running-oozie-actions-in-parallel)

Comment: Can i perform the same with JobClient API ?

Comment: Thanks to Urkia. This will help :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988809/running-oozie-actions-in-parallel